# storing vmdk files on multiple drives

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-player, vmdk

I have a vmdk file which can grow to 600 gb, and splits every 2 gb. Since I physically have 2 x 500gb drives, I would like some of the 2-gig vmdk's to be on D:\, and the rest be on E:.

I edited the master vmdk file (which lists all the 2-gig vmdk files) and tried giving each a full file path. However when I boot the virtual machine I get an error saying "unable to open [master vmdk filename]"

Any ideas if it's possible to split those sub-vmdk files across multiple drives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path has to be relative to the master vmdk file ([doco](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vddk/vmdk_50_technote.pdf)). Create a symbolic link using [junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) so the vmdk thinks it's referring to a subdirectory whereas in fact it's referencing E:\

```
junction "D:\VMs\VirtualMachineA\e-drive" "E:\VirtualMachineA\"
```

Then edit the master vmdk file eg:

```
RW 4192256 SPARSE "/e-drive/VirtualMachineA-s101.vmdk"
```